# Magento image and js / css cache buttons not showing after restoring backup

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, cache

We had to restore a backup (files & database) of our Magento-1.7 store. But after we restored the backup, in `system > cache management`, the cache buttons for image cache and js / css cache is not shown. This is a problem because some images are pointing to the wrong cache file which isn`t existing in our restored backup.

I have tried re-uploading magento 1.7 core files for `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\` but no luck yet. I also deleted cache from server, browser and logged out and in back again. The whole site and backend is working just fine, but these particular buttons are just not showing up.

Any tips on where I start looking for this issue, what adminhtml file is building up this page or what might be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: did you checked the permission of var folder?

Comment: Yeah, it's 755, should be fine right? Isn't the image cache etc. stored inside media/catalog?

Comment: most probably 2 reason. atleast i met with.. one is the permission of media and var folders.. another one is the flash installed in browser.. you please check both..

Comment: Ok, i`ll check both and let you know if it worked out, thanks!